# A four-digit number is to be made using 0,1,2,3,4,5. Find probability of following.

Tags: probability, permutations

I know the concept of the question is repeated. I just want to cross verify my answers as my answers are not matching with textbook.

A four digit number is to be formed from {0,1,2,3,4,5} without repeating any digit. Find the probability that the digit formed is (i) odd (ii) > 4000 (iii) > 3400 (iv) multiple of 5

[Question pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCkRX.png)

This is my solution:
`n(S)` = <sup>6</sup>P<sub>4</sub> = `360`

(i) odd :

`n(A)` = <sup>5</sup>P<sub>3</sub> * <sup>3</sup>P<sub>1</sub> = `180`
`P(A)` = `180/360` = `1/2`

But textbook says its `12/25`

(ii) > 4000

`n(B)` = <sup>2</sup>P<sub>1</sub> * <sup>5</sup>P<sub>3</sub> = `120`
`P(B)` = `120/360` = `1/3`

But textbook says its `2/5`

(iii) > 3400

`n(C)` = <sup>2</sup>P<sub>1</sub> * <sup>5</sup>P<sub>3</sub> + <sup>1</sup>P<sub>1</sub> * <sup>2</sup>P<sub>1</sub> * <sup>4</sup>P<sub>2</sub> = `144`
`P(C)` = `144/360` = `2/3`

But textbook says its `12/25`

(iv) multiple of 5

`n(D)` = <sup>5</sup>P<sub>3</sub> * <sup>2</sup>P<sub>1</sub> = `120`
`P(D)` = `120/360` = `1/3`

But textbook says its `9/25`

What I am doing wrong,If i am?

Comment: "*Four digit numbers*" do not include $0$ as a leading digit.  $0123$ is a three digit number more commonly written as $123$ as it is greater than $99$ and less than $1000$

Answer (score 1):

To find total count of valid $4$ digit numbers, we find how many of $360$ arrangements have leftmost digit as zero and subtract them.

That is simply  $5 \times 4 \times 3 = 60$

So total count of valid $4$ digit numbers $ = 360 - 60 = 300$.

Now we count valid $4$ digit odd numbers which is

$3 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 - 3 \times 4 \times 3 = 144$

That leads to probability of $\frac{12}{25}$.

You can complete the rest similarly.